Getting 403 status with my account gen for Param Gaming
I have included all the main needed headers that are given in the endpoint request however I am still getting a 403. Which obviously means forbidden. Very new to this so haven't got much idea what i'm doing however I am told this should be working.
this is the endpoint URL: https://paramgaming.com/api/v1/user/signup
Any help is extremely appriciated.
This is my current code
import requests

# Define the URL of the form submission endpoint
url = 'https://paramgaming.com/api/v1/user/signup'

# Define the data to be submitted, assuming it's a dictionary
form_data = {
    'email': 'hjskdfkjshd@gmail.com',
    'password': 'Example9222',
    'referCode': '9E9DB2890A',
    # Add more fields as needed
}

# Define headers if needed
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)',
    'method': 'POST',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cookie': 'connect.sid=s%3ALwmqc4NrpJnt_f827oD-vNClyk2hJOA_.BX997BOyCtA1WNSm%2FHM8siFqSQAWjR7aHhm%2FT0YgqMQ; __cf_bm=vK7Md4y4kSfUD4OncFtpM4CvGPVHx7mMJAkMNx5xP5U-1713303566-1.0.1.1-p_RRTI2mVqw4Tx7M8HbZQwRPjdQsr1RlxtIqR02.dJIyA3avWPcLWQuNePG7zGnJmxWEg7TcSSi4BDIswd0q9A; cf_clearance=2cyDdSR.CeyW27jGNzeLf5CYBrWrwym8ldITE9fcgs0-1713303990-1.0.1.1-0a.GNYZyTCo4GVxrV2qUb2Hy1RyolgBVK_0RsG2hcs98v0_7inG_467QLtzyn2RLzvPXeUGg583L0._yCt58lQ',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Referer': 'https://paramgaming.com/?referCode=9E9DB2890A',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'path': '/api/v1/user/signup',
    'Origin': 'https://paramgaming.com',
    'scheme': 'https'
    # Add more headers as needed
}

# Define the number of times to submit the form
num_submissions = 1

# Loop to submit the form multiple times
for _ in range(num_submissions):
    # Make the POST request
    response = requests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=headers)
    
    # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Form submitted successfully!")
    else:
        print("Form submission failed with status code:", response.status_code)


https://paramgaming.com/api/v1/user/signup — where did you get this API? Is there any documentation?

Websites did nto remain idle, they have various different ways to find out if a request comes from a real user or not.
They could simply have had the nginx vhosts.conf file configured in a way to return 403 statuscode if a POST Request is made were not allowed, if a blocked useragent or referrer is used etc.
Another cause could be that the request is detected (missing tls fingerprint spoofing?) in which case a libary like tls-client could help you out: https://pypi.org/project/tls-client/
You should do the request manually in the browser whole having devtools open so yo can inspect the request and then copy the exact same headers into your python script.
If this helped you, a upvote and mark as solved would mean a lot to me, thank's in advance.
